# Difference between add constraint syntax in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

So, I am applying foreign key constraint on a column in MySQL table.

What I noticed is that I am able to do that in two ways -

```
ALTER TABLE book ADD CONSTRAINT fk_code_id FOREIGN KEY(book_type) REFERENCES code(id);
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE book ADD FOREIGN KEY(book_type) REFERENCES code(id);
```

Why do we have two ways in place to achieve same thing?

Comment: Arguably it's not two ways the CONSTRAINT clause is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter table with Constraint option for adding check constraints to MySQL database tables. 
 The add constraint function allows the user to add a constraint name and a constraint condition.

https://razorsql.com/features/mysql_add_constraint.html

And by this `ALTER TABLE book ADD FOREIGN KEY(book_type) REFERENCES code(id)`  you just make fk between two tables.

Answer (score 1):

create a FOREIGN KEY constraint on the "PersonID" column when the "Orders" table is already created, use the following SQL:

**MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:**

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);
```

To allow naming of a FOREIGN KEY constraint, and for defining a FOREIGN KEY constraint on multiple columns, use the following SQL syntax:

**MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:**

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder
FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);
```